# Replace maximum of array by row with 1, otherwise 0

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

Suppose, we have a `A = [3 4 5; 7 1 4]`. I want to make it as `[0 0 1; 1 0 0]`.

I tried this:  `maxa = max(A(:)); A(A==maxa) = 1`;

This is replacing only maximum value of matrix by one. I need maximum value of each row replaced by one and other values by zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it in Java

```
int arr[][] = {{3, 4, 4}, {7, 1, 4}};
        int max = 0000;
        int preVMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            max = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //Consider that given number is max , make it 1
                if (max == 0) {
                    preVMax = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = 1;
                    max = 1;
                } else if (preVMax == arr[i][j]) {
                    preVMax = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = 1;
                } else if(preVMax < arr[i][j]) {
                    preVMax = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j - 1] = 0;
                    arr[i][j] = 1;
                }else{
                    arr[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i2][j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Praveen have you tested above solution to your issue

Answer (score 0):

The code below solving the problem, but in case, we have two or more same values maximum in a row, then one of them should be 1 and other 0. How can we modify this?

```
r = [2 7 6; 4 8 2; 9 2 8];
    r = r';
    [value,index] = max(r(:,:));
    for i = 1:size(r)
        for j = 1:3
    if r(i,j) == value(j)
        r(i,j) = 1;
    else r(i,j) = 0;
    end
        end
    end
    r = r';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MATLAB help for `max`:

> `M = max(A,[],dim)` returns the largest elements along dimension `dim`.
>   For example, if `A` is a matrix, then `max(A,[],2)` is a column vector
>   containing the maximum value of each row.

So if you have a matrix `A = [3 4 5; 7 1 4]`, then

```
maxa = max(A, [], 2)
```

returns the column vector with the maximum of each row, i.e. `[5; 7]`, and then

```
A == maxa
```

will return a logical matrix with `1` where the value of A is equal to the row maximum and `0` otherwise. You can use this logical matrix output of a comparison in an expression or assignment, e.g.:

```
>> ismax = A == max(A, [], 2)

ismax =

  2×3 logical array

   0   0   1
   1   0   0
```